# Matplotlib window closing right after it opens on WSL

Tags: python, matplotlib

Even with the simplest code, a call to `plt.show()` opens a matplotlib that closes after a fraction of a second

The code that follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.show(block=True)
```

opens a matplotlib window and closes it immediately. I checked I was in non-interactive mode, and tried to place an `input()` right after the `plt.show()` but nothing works.

It worked fine 30mn ago but stopped working all of a sudden.

I am on WSL 2 / windows 11

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** I did a clean uninstall and reinstalled matplotlib and it now works, I still haven't figured why it didn't work in the first place

Comment: Did you try using `plt.show(block=False)`?

Comment: I did but it didn't work either